# gettext mipsel misstake

Tags: linux, mips, gettext, endianness

I am trying to install gettext for mipsel gcc. 1sly i am install libiconv-1.13

```
./configure --host=mipsel-linux --prefix=/home/egor/sourses --build=i386-pc-linux-gnu --target=mipsel-linux
make all install
```

no errors

```
./configure --build=i386-pc-linux-gnu --host=mipsel-linux `enter code here`--target=mipsel-linux --prefix=/home/egor/sourse
```

after make i got mistake

```
spawni.c: In function 'gl_posix_spawn_internal':
spawni.c:214: error: 'posix_spawnattr_t' has no member named '_sp'
spawni.c:221: error: 'posix_spawnattr_t' has no member named '_sp'
```